# Criar um novo objeto com o type recebido por parâmetro

Tags: javascript, typescript

Tenho a seguinte classe genérica:

```
class Generic<T> {

}
```

Como faço pra criar um objeto com tipo recebido? Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
class Generic<T> {
    item: T = new T(); // isso é um exemplo, somente pra ilustrar o que preciso.
}
```

Comment: Não acho que esse tipo de abordagem seja possível. Typescript é apenas um wrapper para Javascript, que oferece alguns recursos em tempo de compilação. Isso que você está tentando fazer é algo que teria que ser checado em tempo de execução, quando o Typescript não existe mais, e não existe mais referência ao tipo genérico recebido na sua classe. Se você tiver uma instancia de T, você poderia acessar o construtor por meio da propriedade `constructor` da instancia, mas provavelmente existe uma forma melhor de se fazer o que quer que seja o que você está tentando fazer.

Answer (score 2):

Com a sintaxe pretendida não é possível, pois os tipos [`generics`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) em TypeScript são apenas uma abstração sobre o tipo [`Any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any) para facilitar a inferência sobre propriedades, parâmetros e retornos de métodos.

O mais próximo do que você quer, e que a linguagem permite fazer, é criar um [Genéric Factory](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics) que diferentemente de um [Class Factory](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_Method) a criação de objetos dum determinado tipo não é mais delegada a um subclasse e sim a um tipo genérico.

Na documentação [do TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics) está escrito:

> *Ao criar factories usando genéricos, é necessário fazer referência*
> *aos tipos de classe por suas funções construtoras.*
>
> ```
> function create<T>(c: {new(): T; }): T {
>    return new c();
> }
> ```

Um exemplo prático:

```
interface IClasse{
  printName():void;
}

class Classe1 implements IClasse{
  printName(){
    console.log("Sou a classe1");
  }
}

class Classe2 implements IClasse{
  printName(){
    console.log("Sou a classe2");
  }
}

class Classe3 implements IClasse{
  printName(){
    console.log("Sou a classe3");
  }
}

class Generic<T extends IClasse> {

  //Class factory genérico
  static factory<T>(arg:{new():T}):T{
    return new arg();
  }

}

//Usa o factory para criar algumas instâncias
//e em cada instância criada chama o método printName()
Generic.factory(Classe1).printName();
Generic.factory(Classe2).printName();
Generic.factory(Classe3).printName();
```

Que resulta em:

```
Sou a classe1
Sou a classe2
Sou a classe3
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [ReplIt](https://repl.it/repls/HopefulWhirlwindDecompiler)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar esse conceito de Generics no typescript nas versões mais novas, um exemplo simples:

```
class Generic<T> {
    constructor(arg: T) {
        console.log(`Valor: ${arg}, Tipo: ${typeof arg}`);
    }
}

function main() {
    new Generic<String>('Teste');    
}

main();
```